# A formula for the least common multiple less than n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone please tell me a exact formula for  $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,...n)$ and if its not possible then asymptotic expansion will do.

Comment: Check http://oeis.org/A003418  You will find asymptotic expansions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$lcm(1,2,\ldots,n)=\prod_{p\le n} p^{\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor}$$

Where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes floor, and the product is over primes less than or equal to $n$.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n) = e^{\psi(n)}$$ where $\psi(n)$ is the second [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). Some asymptotic for $\psi(n)$ are known. For instance, we have $\psi(n) \sim n$.