# Finding the minimum number which can be divided by $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .......1000)$ without remaining?

Tags: number-theory

If I want to find the minimum number which can be divided by 2, 3, 4...10 without remaining, the solution will be  N=2520
But If the range of numbers become very wide, how can I find this minimum number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503581/a-formula-for-the-least-common-multiple-less-than-n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take the example of $10$. You need to divide $8$ (the highest power of $2$ below $10$), $9$ (the highest power of $3$ below $10$), $5$ (the highest power of $5$ below $10$) and $7$ (the highest power of $7$ below $10$).

Thus the result is $8*9*5*7 = 2520$.

From our approach you can now deduce the general formula for the limit L : 
$$\prod_{p=2,\ p\in\mathbb{P}}^{L}p^{\lfloor \log_pL\rfloor}$$

Where $p$ is the summation index, and $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers.

As for the practicabillity of this formula, I suggest you to use a computer for the calculation. Simply run an Erathosetenes' sieve to get all the primes from $2$ to $1000$, and then compute the product.

Comment: This formula not exact solution

Comment: Can I use it to find the exact solution?

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: What is the meaning of "p"

Comment: @elegh You didn't ask for "exact solution"; you asked "how can I find" and that's what this answer tells you.

Comment: @Traklon Shouldn't the expression below the product just say "$p \in \mathbb{P}$"?

Comment: @Ryan : I've never seen a subscript like "$n\in \mathbb{N}$" with an upper limit so I like this way. Anyway it's purely cosmetic ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the lcm of 2,3,...,1000 is gigantic. For instance, lcm(2,3,...,100)$\approx 6.9720\times 10^{40}$. I have implemented the WP section [Finding least common multiples by prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization) in MATLAB. Here is the code:

```
n=100;
p=primes(n); %row vector
X=zeros(n-1,length(p));
for i=1:n-1
   v=factor(i+1);
   for j=1:length(v)
      X(i,:)=X(i,:)+(p==v(j)); 
   end
end
lcm=1;
for i=1:length(p)
    lcm=lcm*p(i).^(max(X(:,i)));
end
lcm
```

---

**Addendum I**

This question inspired me to write a MATLAB routine with arbitrary precision. It turns out lcm(2,3,4,...,1000) has 433 digits. You can see them all by using the script found [here](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48312-n-argument-least-common-multiple-calculator-with-arbitrary-precision).

---

**Addendum II**

For a graphical plot of what lhf was explaining, we can plot $\psi(n):=\log[lcm(1,2,...,n)]$ vs. $n$ using the above referenced script and we see that, indeed, $\psi(n)\approx n$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The smallest number that is a multiple of $2,3,\ldots,n$ is by definition $lcm(2,3,\ldots,n)$.

This is given by
$$
lcm(1,2,\ldots,n)
= \prod_{p\le n} p^{\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor}
$$

We can re-write this as
$$
lcm(1,2,\ldots,n) = e^{\psi(n)}
$$

where $\psi$ is the [second Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function):
$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k\le x}\log p
= \sum_{p\le x}\lfloor\log_p x\rfloor\log p,
$$

There is no explicit formula for $\psi$, but there are asymptotic results.
For instance,
$$
\psi(x) \sim x
$$
which is equivalent to the prime number theorem.
More detailed asymptotics are related to the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: See also [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).