# Is there a simple formula for this lcm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a simple formula for $\mathsf{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n-1,n)$ that can be explicitly stated out?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834220/least-common-multiple-lim-sqrtn1-2-dotsc-n-e

Comment: See [OEIS A$3418$](http://oeis.org/A003418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).
It can be written as
$$
lcm(1,2,\ldots,n)
= \prod_{p\le n} p^{\lfloor \log_p n \rfloor}
$$
and so
$$
lcm(1,2,\ldots,n) = e^{\psi(n)}
$$

where $\psi$ is the [second Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function):
$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k\le x}\log p
= \sum_{p\le x}\lfloor\log_p x\rfloor\log p,
$$

There is no explicit formula for $\psi$, but there are asymptotic results.
For instance,
$$
\psi(x) \sim x
$$
which is equivalent to the prime number theorem.
More detailed asymptotics are related to the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: Adapted from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/999649/589.

Comment: maybe writing $\displaystyle e^{\psi(n+\epsilon)}$ would be more careful

Comment: @user1952009, why? $lcm(1,2,\ldots,n) = e^{\psi(n)}$ is exact.

Comment: @ lhf : because in nearly every formula it is $\psi_0(x)$ which appears so it is safer to write $\psi(n+\epsilon)$